# Send a bash command to terminal's created server of codeanywhere.com website in websocket

Tags: php, websocket

I want to connect to websocket of https://codeanywhere.com/ website, and send a bash command to terminal's created server.

[image]

I find url by inspect of chrome, be like this:
`wss://terminal.codeanywhere.com/socket.io/?token=a2dc3aaf74fd86450403a32f14134841fb5a32a2c3e38eb8&tabId=2233322-ae3c7ce8-17df-46c9-bf7b-22895ba7b6b7&connectionId=2233322&path=&EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=zH9jTMre4I-HK4E8IyJY`

I use [`"ratchet/pawl": "^0.3.4"`](https://github.com/ratchetphp/Pawl) package.

And write these code:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$url = 'wss://terminal.codeanywhere.com/socket.io/?token=a2dc3aaf74fd86450403a32f14134841fb5a32a2c3e38eb8&tabId=2233322-ae3c7ce8-17df-46c9-bf7b-22895ba7b6b7&connectionId=2233322&path=&EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=zH9jTMre4I-HK4E8IyJY';
$headers = [
    'Host' => 'terminal.codeanywhere.com',
    'Connection' => 'Upgrade',
    'Pragma' => 'no-cache',
    'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache',
    'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36',
    'Upgrade' => 'websocket',
    'Origin' => 'https://codeanywhere.com',
    'Sec-WebSocket-Version' => '13',
    'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language' => 'en-US,en;q=0.9,fa;q=0.8',
    'Sec-WebSocket-Key' => 'Ge/uFr0UjX62X84vbsE/Ww==',
    'Sec-WebSocket-Extensions' => 'permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits',
];

$loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
$reactConnector = new \React\Socket\Connector($loop);
$connector = new Ratchet\Client\Connector($loop, $reactConnector);
$connector($url, [], $headers)
->then(function(Ratchet\Client\WebSocket $conn) {

    $conn->on('error', function($error) {
        echo "Ratchet Pawl error ({$error})\n";
    });

    $conn->on('message', function(\Ratchet\RFC6455\Messaging\MessageInterface $msg) use ($conn) {
        echo "Received: {$msg}\n";
        //$conn->close();
    });

    $conn->on('open', function() {
        echo "Connection opened\n";
    });

    $conn->on('close', function($code = null, $reason = null) {
        echo "Connection closed ({$code} - {$reason})\n";
    });

    //$conn->send('42["data","ls\r"]');
    $conn->send('2probe');

}, function(\Exception $e) use ($loop) {
    echo "Could not connect: {$e->getMessage()}\n";
    $loop->stop();
});
$loop->run();
```

But I just get this error message:

```
Connection closed (1000 - )
```

What's the problem and what's your solution?

Comment: I would drop the headers altogether and try it - the headers you are sending would interfere with a proper websocket handshake. (Your header specifies compress, which is unsupported by Pawl)

Comment: @mbonneau I ignored each item of header, and then ignored all items of header, but not effective and return same error.